# Firebase firestore set array of objects to document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I need to set an array for objects to firestore but only the first index of urls is getting stored. Any help in the right direction would be helpful thanks.

**Code:**

```
    const object = [
           {
            user: 'mike',
            userName: 'Mike nick',
            Urls:[
              {comment: "BBBBB", imageUrl: "url1"},
              {comment: "BBBJvuyiu", imageUrl: "url2"},
              {comment: "AAAAA", imageUrl: "url3"},
            ],
            date: 'March 20th'
           }
       ]


     firestoreRef
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userId)
        .collection('images')
        .doc('customers')
        .collection('customerExperience')
        .doc(userId)
        .set(object, { merge: true })
```

**need this structure as user may continue to add more data:**

[image]
[image]
    **it looks like this when i upload the object.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your const `object` is actually an Array, when it should be an Object (that is not an Array).

The following should work:

```
  const object = {
    user: 'mike',
    userName: 'Mike nick',
    urls: [
      { comment: 'BBBBB', imageUrl: 'url1' },
      { comment: 'BBBJvuyiu', imageUrl: 'url2' },
      { comment: 'AAAAA', imageUrl: 'url3' }
    ],
    date: 'March 20th'
  };
```

---

Note the difference with your object:

```
const object = [
           {
            .....
           }
       ]
```

---

**UPDATE following your comment:**

If you want to have it saved exactly the way you show in your updated question, do as follows. I am not sure however that this is the best way to save your data: as a matter of fact you are not creating an array but several fields of type "map" with the following names: 0, 1, etc.

One of the main (negative) side effect is that you will need to know all the fields names upfront in order to read them, while with a "genuine" Array field, you can loop over its values.

```
  const object = {
    0: {
      user: 'mike1',
      userName: 'Mike nick',
      urls: [
        { comment: 'BBBBB', imageUrl: 'url1' },
        { comment: 'BBBJvuyiu', imageUrl: 'url2' },
        { comment: 'AAAAA', imageUrl: 'url3' }
      ],
      date: 'March 20th'
    },
    1: {
      user: 'mike2',
      userName: 'Mike nick',
      urls: [
        { comment: 'BBBBB', imageUrl: 'url1' },
        { comment: 'BBBJvuyiu', imageUrl: 'url2' },
        { comment: 'AAAAA', imageUrl: 'url3' }
      ],
      date: 'March 20th'
    }
  };
```

Comment: i tried your method it still not uploading right, can you take a look at my updated question. Thanks

Comment: no quiet what am asking, my only issue is when i upload { comment: 'BBBJvuyiu', imageUrl: 'url2' }, { comment: 'AAAAA', imageUrl: 'url3' } are missing its only shows  { comment: 'BBBBB', imageUrl: 'url1' }. meaning the other objects some how never got uploaded. Thanks.

Comment: On my side, in any case I do see the entire array of urls objects in the database (`{ comment: 'BBBJvuyiu', imageUrl: 'url2' }, { comment: 'AAAAA', imageUrl: 'url3' }, ...`)

Answer (score 0):

**From the [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types), here's the sample code for the different data types:**

```
let data = {
  stringExample: 'Hello, World!',
  booleanExample: true,
  numberExample: 3.14159265,
  dateExample: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date('December 10, 1815')),
  arrayExample: [5, true, 'hello'],
  nullExample: null,
  objectExample: {
    a: 5,
    b: true
  }
};
```

**You will need the following to create an object that contains an array of objects**

```
let object = {
  user: 'mike',
  userName: 'Mike nick',
  urls: {
    [{comment: 'BBBBB', imageUrl: 'url1'},
    {comment: 'BBBJvuyiu', imageUrl: 'url2'},
    {comment: 'AAAAA', imageUrl: 'url3'}]
    },
  date: 'March 20th'
};
```

**Let me know if this works for you.**